# Dialog appears behind other windows

Tags: wpf, dialog, prism

I'm using the Prism dialog service to create an unhandled exception dialog.  I have a splash screen window that, while it doesn't have the `TopMost` property set (tried that and it was totally miserable :), I use `Activate` on it to get it to rise to the top so it appears over the main window as it loads up.

The problem is when an exception is thrown and the unhandled exception dialog that I made pops up, it appears behind the splash screen, leaving the user wondering what happened until they notice an extra button in the task bar.

The dialog is a `UserControl`, as instructed by the documentation, and it has no `Activate` function.  And when I try to get a handle to the parent window in the constructor, the `Parent` property is `null`.

How can I bring a dialog to the top of other windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prism's dialog service sets the [`Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.owner?view=netcore-3.1) of a dialog automatically to the first active `Window` that is found in the `Application.Current.Windows` collection if the dialog window does not already have set an owner. It does not expose any methods to access or activate windows directly. In an MVVM service you would not do that.

In Prism <= 7.x, you can only have a single dialog window host. By default this is a regular `Window`. You have to share this dialog host window type for all of your dialogs, so setting a different `Owner` in a custom `Window` is not an option. Since `Owner` is `null` when a `Window` is instantiated, its owner will be the first active window.

This behavior is problematic if you want the `Owner` of your dialog to be a different window like your splash screen, so it appears on top of it automatically or modally or have no owner at all.

You cannot activate the dialog in the constructor of your `UserControl`, as it cannot be set as the `Content` of the parent dialog host `Window` before it is instantiated. You either have to use the `Application.Current.Windows` collection to find the dialog or create a custom dialog service for now for both activating or setting an `Owner`.

### Application Windows

If you want to find the dialog host window in `Application.Current.Windows`, you can filter this collection after showing the dialog and check the `Content` of each window, one will contain your `UserControl` type. If you only show the unhandled exception dialog once, there will be a single window instance with this `UserControl`. If you show it multiple times, you could identify the current instance via a property on its view model accessible by `DataContext` that you have set before by passing a `DialogParameter` in `Show`. Consider creating a service.

### Custom Dialog Service

Personally, I prefer creating a custom dialog service, as it gives you more control over what you are doing. To create a custom interface that exposes the methods of the built-in `IDialogService`, as well as your own methods, depeding on your requirements.

```
public interface ICustomDialogService : IDialogService
{
   public void ShowOrphan(string name, IDialogParameters parameters, Action<IDialogResult> callback);
}
```

I simply create a new method `ShowOrphan` to show a dialog that has no owner and is activated automatically when shown, so it is in the foreground. Adapt it to your requirements, like passing in an explicit owner or just an owner type, so that the dialog service searches an instance in the application window collection itself.

Next, implement the `ICustomDialogService` in a `CustomDialogService` type. You can just copy the code from the [public repository](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogService.cs). Be sure to use the code for your version of Prism, see *Tags*.

You do not have to change much. Just pass appropriate parameters from your new public method down the `ConfigureDialogWindowProperties` method, which is responsible for setting the window owner. If activating the dialog window is really necessary apart from showing it, you can do that in `ShowDialogInternal`.

```
public class CustomDialogService : ICustomDialogService
{
   // ...other public members.

   public void ShowOrphan(string name, IDialogParameters parameters, Action<IDialogResult> callback)
   {
      // Appended a new parameter "isOrphan"
      ShowDialogInternal(name, parameters, callback, false, true);
   }

   // ...other private members.

   // Appended a new parameter "isOrphan"
   void ConfigureDialogWindowProperties(IDialogWindow window, FrameworkElement dialogContent, IDialogAware viewModel, bool isOrphan)
   {
      // ...other code.

      if (isOrphan)
         return;

      if (window.Owner == null)
         window.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
   }
}
```

If you are done, you have to overwrite the registration for the old dialog service.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton <CustomDialogService>();
containerRegistry.Register<IDialogService, CustomDialogService>();
containerRegistry.Register<ICustomDialogService, CustomDialogService>();
```

Now you can resolve the `ICustomDialogService` and use its `ShowOrphan` method to show the window.

Comment: Actually, this solution isn't working for me.  The exception window stills show up under the splash window.  The splash screen window doesn't appear in `Application.Current.Windows`.  I think it's because the SplashScreenWindow is started in another thread?

Comment: @MattGregory If your splash screen window is started on another thread, you cannot use it as an `Owner` of a window that is not on that thread. However, you can create a window without an owner as shown in the answer and call `Activate` on it in the dialog service after `Show` or `ShowDialog`. This will bring it to the front.

Comment: I can't do that because IDialogWindow does not inherit from Window, so it has no Activate() method.

Comment: Yeah, I tried replacing your `bool isOrphan` parameter with a `Window owner` parameter, and Bill Gates was not happy at all about that.

Comment: I can cast `dialogContent.Parent` to a `Window` and call `Activate`, or cast the `window` to a `Window` and call `Activate`, but neither of these techniques is succeeding in bringing the window to the top.

Comment: Ah, I've got it!  I was doing it too soon: the window wasn't shown yet.  I had to throw it in the Dispatcher queue.